# Skype Web SDK stops updating presence

Tags: ionic2, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am using Skype Web SDK with ionic.

I have two buttons in app after login like "Idle" and "Busy". When I click on it, its changing status of user on Skype for business o365 accordingly.

Now, When I run the app, After login, its work well for first one hour or so and then the app stops reflecting status on Skype For Business.

I get 404 - not found error once it stops updating status.

POST https://webpooldb41e02.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/1145363530/me/reportMyActivity 404 (Not Found)

below is the code I am using for authentication,

```
let authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");
authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync("https://graph.windows.net", "Client_id")
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);

            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
            Skype.initialize({
                apiKey: 'Api Key'
            }, function (api) {
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleString()+" 2");
            console.log(api.UIApplicationInstance);
            //console.log(this.ucwaData);
                window.skypeWebApp = "";
                window.skypeWebApp = api.UIApplicationInstance;    

                window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.signIn({
                    "client_id": client_id,
                    "origins": ["https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root"],    
                    "cors": true,
                    "version": 'SkypeOnlinePreviewApp/1.0.0',
                    "redirect_uri": 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient'
                }).then(function () {

                    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString()+" done");

                });
            }, function (err) {
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleString()+" 3");

                console.log(err);   
            }); 
        }, function () {
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
            // We require user credentials so triggers authentication dialog
            authContext.acquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", "client_id", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
            .then(function(res){
                if (typeof(document.getElementById("login_with_office")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("login_with_office") != null)
                {
                    document.getElementById("login_with_office").innerHTML = "Please wait … Connecting";
                }
                console.log(res);
            //document.getElementById("login_with_office").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                ctrl.loginwitho365();       
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(new Date().toLocaleString()+" Failed to authenticate: " + err);
            });
        });
```

And Below is the code I am using for updating status,

```
window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.state.get().then(function (stat) {
if(stat == "SignedIn")
{
    window.skypeWebApp.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.status.set(availability); 
}
else
{
    //Signin COde
}
});
```